# Where should I stop my Async task myAsync.cancel(true)

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-fragments

I have several fragments and every fragment has an unblocking async call which updates the UI in its onPostExecute.

The issue is that if the user switches to other fragment while the async is still executing, this results in NullPointerException.

I tried cancelling async task in the onDestroy of every fragment but still exception occur. WHICH IS THE IDEAL METHOD TO STOP ALL MY ASYNC?

Is it onDestroy for Fragments???

```
asyncTask.cancel(true);
```

Please help!

Comment: We can't tell what produces the exception without knowing what AsyncTask does, whether you handle isCancelled() and crashlogs.

Comment: the async task is a network call. And my list is updated in onPostExecute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually want to put that in `onPause`. `onDestroy` isn't guaranteed to be called, `onPause` is the last place. And there isn't really a good reason to still be loading a GUI after `onPause`. Start your `AsyncTask` in `onResume`.

From the [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) page:

> **onPause()** Called when the system is about to start resuming a previous activity. This is typically used to commit unsaved changes to persistent data, stop animations and other things that may be consuming CPU, etc.

This seems to be the best place to stop your AsyncTask, per the documents.

Comment: onPause() can be called if the Dialog is shown upon, so better idea is to use onStop().

Comment: Yes, but `onStop` might never be called. Still, it is more likely to be called than `onDestroy`, so...

Comment: You have a point there, but onPause is called when the dialog is shown so the task will be canceled while user doesn't want it to be cancelled. Moreover, if there are such large pressure, AsyncTask is likely to be killed along with the Activity and Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop your `AsyncTask` objects in the `onPause()` method.  But the `AsyncTask` object's `onCancelled()` and `onPostExecute()` methods still run on the UI thread once your `doInBackground()` method returns.  You'll need to have protection code in your `onPostExecute()` to ensure you're not automatically touching UI components or manipulating the `Fragment`.

Comment: onPostExecute() is not called after cancel(boolean)

Comment: > Calling this method guarantees that onPostExecute(Object) is never invoked. [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29)